# How to pass pipeline variables to an external script?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure dev ops pipeline that is referencing a bash script, which is part of the repo.
The bash script needs to use the pipeline variables in order to work.
So how do I make those variables usable inside the bash script too?

Let's say my pipeline variables are called : **pipeline_foo and pipeline_bar**
This is how I try to "export"/pass them to the script.sh

this is part of the pipeline yaml:

```
    FooJobs:
      - job: SomeJobName
        displayName: "SomeJobName"
        condition: eq(variables['SKIP_XYZ'], 'false')
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 1
            fetchTags: false
            displayName: Permissions setup
          - script: "chmod +x ./scripts/script.sh"
            displayName: ScriptStuffBelow
          - script: |
              pipeline_foo=$(pipeline.variable "pipeline_foo")
              pipeline_bar=$(pipeline.variable "pipeline_bar")
              "./scripts/script.sh"
            displayName: Run the super awesome script
```

this is how i try to call them in script.sh:

```
pipeline_foo=$(pipeline.variable "pipeline_foo")
pipeline_bar=$(pipeline.variable "pipeline_bar")
```

[I tried reading through the docs but i couldn't understand it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables). Maybe because my english is not that great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish there are a few options.

I can't see where the pipeline variables are defined and what their exact name is. I'll assume the `pipeline_foo` and `pipeline_bar` you've mentioned are correct.

If these variables don't contain a secret, then they are made available to the script automatically as an environment variable, but their name is transformed to uppercase:

```yaml
         - script: |
              pipeline_foo=$PIPELINE_FOO
              pipeline_bar=$PIPELINE_BAR
              "./scripts/script.sh"
            displayName: Run the super awesome script
```

You probably won't even need the assignment in the script block, but would just need to update `script.sh` to uppercase the variable names.

If the variable contains a secret, they're not automatically passed to the environment of the script, you need to pass them explicitly:

```yaml
         - script: |
              "./scripts/script.sh"
            displayName: Run the super awesome script
            env:
              pipeline_foo: $(pipeline_foo)
              pipeline_bar: $(pipeline_bar)
```

There are other options, but **the above 2 are the safest solutions**, since they automatically solve any problems with quotes and other character escaping.

Instead of passing the values through the environment, you can inline them directly in the script:

```yaml
         # ⚠️ May break if the variable contains a "
         - script: |
              pipeline_foo="$(pipeline_foo)"
              pipeline_bar="$(pipeline_bar)"
              "./scripts/script.sh"
           displayName: Run the super awesome script
```

Or you can pass them as arguments to the script:

```yaml
         # ⚠️ May break if the variable contains a "
         - task: Bash@3
           inputs:
             filePath: "./scripts/script.sh" 
             arguments: "$(pipeline_foo) $(pipeline_bar)"
           displayName: Run the super awesome script
```

And again, you can optionally pass the environment:

```yaml
         - task: Bash@3
           inputs:
             filePath: "./scripts/script.sh" 
           displayName: Run the super awesome script
           env: 
             pipeline_foo: $(pipeline_foo)
             pipeline_bar: $(pipeline_bar)
```

[The syntax you've used in the original question is the syntax for setting the special `BASH_ENV` environment variable.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines#info-about-bash-startup-files) This syntax isn't needed for what you're trying to accomplish.